# Wann ging der häufige Gebrauch des »th« verloren?

Tags: history

In alten deutschen Texten liest man häufig Wörter mit th geschrieben, die heutzutage ohne ein Solches geschrieben werden. Beispiele sind *Theil*, *Thor*. Wann wurden diese Schreibungen abgeschafft? Nach welchem Kriterium wurden sie in anderen Wörtern wie *Thron* behalten?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Willkürlich habe ich nach einigen dieser Begriffe in NGrams gesucht. Einige sind dabei unauffällig (Thor/Tor, möglicherweise in diesem Fall, weil es den Namen Thor ja auch noch gibt). Andere, zum Beispiel Theil/Teil, Werth/Wert, Wirth/Wirt, zeigen einen typischen Verlauf:

[image: Kurvenverlauf für Werth/Wert]

Hier ist auffällig, dass der Wechsel kurz vor der Jahrhundertwende um 1900 erfolgte. 1876 fand die [Erste Orthographische Konferenz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1876) statt, die eine Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Rechtschreibung erzielen sollte:

> Ferner sollte das th, das in deutschen Wörtern wie Zierat, Armut längst wankend geworden war, jetzt im Auslaut und in den Endungen -tum, tüm ganz wegfallen und nur im Anlaut vor einfachen Vokalen stehen bleiben, also Glut, Not, Atem, Altertum, Ungetüm, auch Teil, verteidigen; aber That, Thor, Unterthan wie bisher.

1901 fand die [Zweite Orthographische Konferenz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901) statt:

> In heimischen Wörtern sollte das h nach t grundsätzlich fallen (Tal, Tür statt Thal, Thür). In Fremdwörtern wie Thron und Theater wurde die th-Schreibung beibehalten.

(Beide Zitate aus Wikipedia)

Comment: Beibehalten wurde auch "Thüringen".