# Dropped 'H' in 1901 Orthography Conference

Tags: history, spelling

In 1901, was the letter 'H' dropped in some words where not needed? I think "thun" was a example. What other words were affected? Was "Tür" (door) one of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Might best be a community wiki, since it is a more or less open list.

Comment: There was already a [similar question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/wann-ging-der-haufige-gebrauch-des-th-verloren), also mentioning *Tür*.

Answer (score 6):

One resolution of the orthography conference in 1901 was to omit the letter *h* after *t* in German words (not in words of foreign origin and in Germanic words like *Thing* and *Thor*; also, the word *Thron* kept its *th* because of German emperor Wilhelm II's intervention.)

Other examples:

- Thal → Tal
- thun → tun
- Thau → Tau (as in *Morgentau*)
- Thon → Ton
- ...

A simple way to look up old words is to use the online version of

**[Das deutsche Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB)**

You can in fact see that *Tür* was spelled *thür* before the orthography conference in 1901.

> THÜR, thüre, f. ahd. turi duri und tura dura, mhd. tür und türe (eigentlich plural), md. tur dur und ture dure, alts. dura, ags. duru, altfries. dure, altn. dyr, meist nur in pluraler form auftretend, wie denn auch das ahd. turi eigentlich ein zum singular gewordener plural ist, und der begriff 'thür' in den indogerm. sprachen vielfach als dual (die beiden thürflügel) oder als plural erscheint, s. Kluge in den beiträgen von Paul und Braune 8, 512, Sievers ebenda 5, 111 anm. aus dem gemeinindogerm. stamm dhur, dessen ursprüngliche bedeutung nicht zu ermitteln ist, sind auch hervorgegangen skr. dvâr (ved. dur), griech. θύρα, lat. fores. altslav. dvĭrĭ (und dvorŭ hof), lit. durys u. s. w., s. Curtius3 242f. Fick3 3, 151. gramm. 3, 430. vgl. DWB thor n., mit dem thür oft verbunden vorkommt. — die jetzige schwache form des plurals ist früher auch im dativ singular nachweisbar, z. b. über der thüren Eulensp. 66 (40) neudr., vor der 67 (41), zu der thüren 74 (47), under der thüren F. Platter 230, an der thüren Maaler 401a, in der thüren Gryphius horrib. 59 neudruck. 
>   1) die thür ist eine zum ein- und ausgang oder zum ein- und austhun (an behältern) bestimmte öffnung sowie die bewegliche (gewöhnlich auf angeln ruhende) verschluszfläche derselben, im engern sinne besonders die haus-, saal-, zimmer-, kammerthür;

Other

Comment: Gab es eigentlich (schriftlich fixierte) Regeln dafür, wann früher "th" oder "t" zu verwenden war?

Comment: @bernd_k ja. Siehe Antwort. Natürlich waren sie vor 1901 nicht ganz offiziell.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Rechtschreibung_im_sp%C3%A4ten_19._Jahrhundert) now presents the rules, which it claims to have taken from the 1895 Duden.

```
Folgende sieben ursprünglich deutschen Wörter müssen mit „th“ geschrieben werden:

Thal, Thon, Thor (der und das), Thran, Thräne, thun und Thür
sowie deren Ableitungen.

Beispiel: Thaler, thönern, thöricht, thranig, thränen, thätig, Unterthan
Weitere Wörter und deren Ableitungen können mit „th“ oder „t“ geschrieben werden, 
wobei die Schreibweise mit „t“ favorisiert wird:

Thau/Tau, Thee/Tee, Theer/Teer, Theil/Teil, theuer/teuer, Thibet/Tibet, Thier/Tier
```

So, there were rules, but prior to the First Orthographic Conference (1876) they weren’t really applied to big parts of the German speaking world. I will try to look deeper into th and see what more I can find.